# How to html report to any printable file

Tags: php, html, file, report

How to html report to any printable file.Is there any solution.

Comment: Please add much more detail to this question as it's very difficult to determine what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to print the current html page, right?

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.print();">Print Page</a>
```